# How to write a query to compare user define fields from sql and sapb1?

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

I am having a task to compare "user define fields" in SAP B1 and SQL Server.

I need the list of related document numbers where having the length of "user define field" in a SAP B1 table which is greater than the length of "user define field" table in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP B1 stores it's user field schema for both system tables and UDTs in the CUFD table. You can compare this to the information schema MS-SQL provides with a simple join:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM CUFD
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     ON CUFD.TableID = TABLE_NAME
     AND CONCAT ('U_',CUFD.AliasID) = COLUMN_NAME
WHERE (
       cufd.typeid = 'A' AND EditSize <> CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
      )
```

This query only compares simple alphanumeric fields, you can expand it to include other field types if you need to. It probably won't work on Hana based systems.

Comment: Hi.. Mr.Daz, can you please help me out from my new requirement?

Comment: @TarunNurat you should at least vote on whether this answer is correct or not first!

Comment: the answer was some what helpful to me, But if i get the answer for my new request, i can solve my problem completely.

Comment: @Daz Hello, I have a question related to this. Is there a way we can get the value in the UDF if we have the TableID and AliasID? The actual use is: I have created UDFs on the table OITM. As the input, I only have the FieldID/AliasID. I want the value in the OITM table related to the UDF. Something of this sort: SELECT * FROM OITM T0 INNER JOIN CUFD T1 ON T0.<columnname> = CONCAT('U_',T1.AliasID) AND T1.TableID = 'OITM' WHERE T0.ItemCode = MyItemCode

Comment: @WishIWasACoder sounds like you need to construct some dynamic SQL. Try https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Daz Hi, I need to use the result in an inline table-valued function and can't use dynamic SQL. Is there a way to link column ids/names in SAP B1 that can be used instead?